# Ordenar array multidimensional por el valor de una key alfanumérica sin que cambie los índices

Tags: php, array, ordenamiento

Tengo un array como el siguiente:

```
$lista = [
      '867Ad2' => [
         stock => 2,
         nombre => "cosa1",
      ]
      '838sdff2' => [
         stock => 4,
         nombre => "cosa2",
      ]
      '234hsd4fd' => [
         stock => 6,
         nombre => "cosa3",
      ]  
      '8691240654d' => [
         stock => 8,
         nombre => "cosa4",
      ]
    ]
```

Me lo ordena como yo quiero, por el valor de la key `'stock'` de esta manera:

```
function orderBy($data, $field)
            {
                $code = "return strnatcmp(\$b['$field'], \$a['$field']);";
                sort($data, create_function('$a,$b', $code));
                return $data;
            }

            $sorted_data = orderBy($lista, 'stock');
```

Sin embargo me he dado cuenta que al ordenarlo sustituye los índices de la siguiente manera:

```
$lista = [
      '0' => [
         stock => 8,
         nombre => "cosa4",
      ]
      '1' => [
         stock => 6,
         nombre => "cosa3",
      ]
      '2' => [
         stock => 4,
         nombre => "cosa2",
      ]  
      '3' => [
         stock => 2,
         nombre => "cosa1",
      ]
    ]
```

Es decir, sustituye mis índices que son códigos con letras y números, por un índice numérico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero, al usar `create_function` implícitamente estás usando `eval`, que es una práctica desaconsejada. [Citando la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.create-function.php):

> **Precaución** Esta función realiza internamente un eval() y como tal
>   tiene los mismos problemas de seguridad que eval(). Además posee
>   características malas de rendimiento y uso de memoria.

Segundo, lo que quieres hacer, para **mantener los índices** y a la vez ordenar por una función arbitraria se puede hacer con [uasort](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uasort.php), y usar una función anónima:

```
<?php
$lista = [
      '867Ad2' => [
         'stock' => 2,
         'nombre' => "cosa2",
      ],
      '838sdff2' => [
         'stock' => 1,
         'nombre' => "cosa1",
      ],
      '234hsd4fd' => [
         'stock' => 9,
         'nombre' => "cosa9",
      ],  
      '8691240654d' => [
         'stock' => 8,
         'nombre' => "cosa8",
      ]
    ];

uasort($lista, function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a['stock'] == $b['stock']) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a['stock'] < $b['stock']) ? -1 : 1;
        });         


print_r($lista);
```

La salida es

```
Array
(
    [838sdff2] => Array
        (
            [stock] => 1
            [nombre] => cosa1
        )

    [867Ad2] => Array
        (
            [stock] => 2
            [nombre] => cosa2
        )

    [8691240654d] => Array
        (
            [stock] => 8
            [nombre] => cosa8
        )

    [234hsd4fd] => Array
        (
            [stock] => 9
            [nombre] => cosa9
        )

)
```

`uasort` pasa el array por referencia, de manera que tu array original es mutado. No necesitas capturar el array ordenado en un nuevo array.

[Te dejo un fiddle funcionando](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a6a09e14764e17ec02ad735f676e0ea7fb19056).

PS: dentro de tu función anónima perfectamente puedes usar `strnatcmp`

```
    uasort($lista, function ($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a['stock'], $b['stock']);
    });
```

Mi respuesta usó una versión más rudimentaria de comparación sólo para que se entendiera cómo funciona este closure internamente. Te serviría por ejemplo si quisieras comparar por un segundo campo en caso de que `stock` fuera igual.